# Generating the designer file for an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Here I want to generate the designer file like default.aspx.designer.cs file for the page default.aspx. i had been seen it in may application but i don't know how it be happened so please tell me some solution .

Comment: `i saw it`? Saw what? Can you please read your question and think about rephrasing it so people can understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.designer.cs` files are automatically generated by visual studio itself. When you open a webpage is design mode, visual studio writes the `.designer.cs` file to match what you have put on the page.

These files are hidden in the Solution Explorer by default, unless the web project is set to "Show all files", which may be why you have not noticed them until now.

Comment: thanks to reply me, ok but is there should be any settings in visual studio about this functionality. because i had never been seen it in my application .

Comment: @Abhisheks.net - You probably did not see it because by default a web project is not set to "Show all files". Visual Studio hides these unless this is set on the project (one of the buttons at the top of the Solution Explorer).

Comment: yes , but how can i see it. i see the all top buttons but there is no one for show all file , i am using vs 2010 . there are "properties" "refresh" "nest related files" class diagram" "copy website" and "asp.net configuration" please tell me how can i do it.

Comment: @Abhisheks.net - Click on the project file or within the web project, then you should see a "Show all Files" button.

Comment: thanks to help me but i am sorry to say i still didn't able to see it . i tried everything but...

Comment: @Abhisheks.net - I don't know what the issue is. On my VS 2010 the button is there in the Solution Explorer. Are you sure you are using the right window?

Comment: its ok buddy , i found out the problem . thanks to help me thanks a lot.